# save a UIImage with my own name?

Tags: objective-c

I am saving `UIImage` with this method :

```
//save to file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

UIImage *imageToSave = newSize;
NSData *binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);

[binaryImageData writeToFile:basePath  atomically:YES];
```

I want to give it my own name( myImage.png). 
where in my code i can insert a name to it ?
thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basePath` is the path of the Documents folder of your app. You have to add the name of the image file to that path.

```
NSString *imagePath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.png"];
```

Then of course use that to save the image instead of `baseImage`.